# Share website content with image on facebook

Tags: php, facebook

How can I share my website content to facebook?
I have already tried **Sharer** and **Dialog**, however those don't display pictures.

**My code:**

```
function facebook_share(){

    FB.init({
        appId      : '1884730308422253',
        status     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.8'
    });

    FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'Come Listen to this Song',
        link: 'http://192.168.0.100/catchthemyoung/student',
        picture: 'http://192.168.0.100/catchthem/images/timeline/EPUQuotgRj.png',
        caption: 'mywebsite.com',
        description: 'msg',
        message: 'msg'
    },

    // callback
    function(response) {
        if (response && !response.error_message) {
            alert('Posting completed.');
        } else {
            alert('Error while posting.');
        }
    }
    );
}
```

Comment: The image needs to be publicly available, so that Facebook can request and store it. `http://192.168.0.100/` is not publicly reachable.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your domain is register with your app id "1884730308422253"
Please add app domain first with website add platform => choose website and add link
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/XXXXXXXXXXXXX[Yourid]/settings/

```
        <div id="fb-root"></div>           
        <script>
            window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                FB.init({
                    appId: '889551921179700',
                    xfbml: true,
                    version: 'v2.8'
                });
            };
            (function (d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                    return;
                }
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>

        <span id="share_button" class="fb-btn">
              <div class="fb_icon"></div>
              <span class="fb-share">
                    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Share
              </span>                 
        </span>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                            document.getElementById('share_button').onclick = function () {
                                FB.ui({
                                    method: 'share',
                                    display: 'popup',
                                    caption: 'Your Title',
                                    picture: 'Your picture',
                                    description: 'Your description',
                                    href: 'Your link',
                                }, function (response) {
                                });
                            }
         </script>
```

Comment: Ok Thank for replay

Comment: Ok the problem was with my image, it's not showing the images in my local system !!